# How can I add a web link to Launchpad?

Tags: mac, macos, launchpad

I would like to have my web apps show in Launchpad. Is there a way to do this?

I search for something like this but only found one solution, and this is a program not available in the App Store. I think there is more than one solution.

Comment: And what solution did you find?

Comment: An app called fluid. But it's out App Store.

Comment: You said, "I would like to set my web apps in my launchpad", explicitly and specifically what are you referring to as " my web apps"?

Comment: url links like a shortcut

Comment: It is still not totally clear what it is you are asking for, although I assumed you wanted to be able to open a Browser, e.g. Safari, to a given URL but have this show as an application in Launchpad. If that is what you're wanting to do, then my answer address that. If this is not want you want to do, then you need to add additional information to your question and be explicit and specific about what it is you are looking to do!

Answer (score 8):

You can use **Script Editor** and **AppleScript** to create an **AppleScript** *application* which opens the **URL** in a *new tab* in **Safari**, as in the following example:

```
set theURL to "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293859/how-can-i-add-a-web-link-in-launchpad"

tell application "Safari"
    tell front window
        set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:theURL})
    end tell
end tell
```

Change the *value* of `set theURL to "..."` to the appropriate **URL**, and then save this as an *application* to the **Applications** folder.

It will then be available to **Launchpad** and **Spotlight**, as well as other ways and means to open any other *application*.

You can also change the icon of the app, and there are instructions on the Internet on how to do that. E.g., [Create custom icons for files or folders on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-custom-icons-files-folders-mac-mchlp2313/mac). Also, if you want to go the more technical route, have a look at: [Create Your Own Custom Icons in OS X 10.7.5 or Later](https://blog.macsales.com/28492-create-your-own-custom-icons-in-10-7-5-or-later)

---

If you use a different Browser then **Safari**, the *code* can be modify as necessary for that particular Browser.

For Google Chrome:

```
set theURL to "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293859/how-can-i-add-a-web-link-in-launchpad"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell front window
        make new tab with properties {URL:theURL}
    end tell
end tell
```

For Firefox:

```
set theURL to "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293859/how-can-i-add-a-web-link-in-launchpad"

tell application "Firefox"
    open location theURL
end tell
```

---

If you get an warning like `"YourApp.app" wants access to control "Google Chrome.app"` every time you run it, you may need to give it Full Disk Access. Go to **System Preferences** then **Security & Privacy** then **Privacy** then **Full Disk Access**, and add your app to the list. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337525/18453) for more.