# Mojave: disable or control the "[SOME_APP_NAME] wants access to control [ANOTHER_APP_NAME (often Finder)] ..."?

Tags: finder, applescript, script, mojave

A new security feature in Mojave revolves around a system dialogue that prompts you to grant access to apps that want to control other apps, such as Finder (I'm finding frequently happening with some apps like Epichrome):

[image]

Is there a known way to disable this or to allow certain destination (controlled apps) to always allow such activity?

I do believe that this behavior has changed markedly from the previous OS releases with regards to just using the "Accessibility" tab to simply allow an application to make system changes.

Here is the new panel:
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to edit the tcc sqlite databases directly (~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db and /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db, the latter of which is only available to the root user) in order to grant an app blanket permissions?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I think it warrants a question in and of itself. If you post it, let me know as I'd like to follow it or if you don't want to I could post it since it seems different enough to warrant it @Wowfunhappy...

Comment: Done. I had originally thought they would be too similar, but I took your advice! (I hope you don't mind that I reused your screenshot!) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339509/editing-tcc-db-to-grant-an-app-blanket-permissions-to-control-your-computer-fo

Comment: Don't have time to fully investigate atm, but I believe the key to actually doing this lies in /System/Library/Sandbox/TCC_Compatibility.bundle/Contents/Resources/AllowedApplicationsList.plist, which contains a list of software Apple allows to send Apple Events without prompts. Protected by SIP, of course, so you'd have to disable that. See also: https://eclecticlight.co/2018/11/20/what-does-the-tcc-compatibility-database-do/

Comment: @Wowfunhappy this is extremely interesting... Thanks for finding this. I too don't have time to dig into this atm, but it's extremely promising.

Comment: To expand on previous theory (which I still haven't tested, since I've done the ridiculous thing of downgrading to Mavericks permanently), you could add launchd to the previously-mentioned `AllowedApplicationsList.plist`. That _might_ blanket allow everything, because everything gets launched by launchd, one way or another.

Answer (score 11):

**Add the app to "Full Disk Access"**

In Mojave, under Security & Privacy, there is a new tab called "Full Disk Access".

Adding my personal Applescript apps to this list (in addition to the existing Accessibility list) has made the prompts disappear.

---

Update 9/26: Upon a couple days of further use, this seems to work sometimes, but not consistently.

Comment: You may need to add the Applescript app to **Security & Privacy** - **Accessibility**

Comment: @ErickYim Nope, that doesn't work consistently in Mojave. :(

Comment: This solution keeps getting upvoted, and while I very much appreciate the rep, to be clear, the answer does not work with the specific type of prompt in the OP. At first, it seemed to sometimes prevent some prompts, but that might have been the placebo effect. And actually, at this point, I think it was *probably* the placebo effect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow programs that will control your computer access through security preferences.  Go to System preferences/ security and privacy/ privacy - accessibility and add Finder.app and "SOME_APP_NAME" to the list of programs allowed to control your computer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I believe this behavior has markedly changed now as per my edit above that you'll now see.

Comment: Do you have an Apple developer account? If you do then you can code sign your AppleScript applications. If your AppleScript application is code signed, that may eliminate a lot of your problems .  https://i.imgur.com/oL3xZ2d.png  I code sign all of my AppleScript applications, and as long as I don't have persistent properties set, code signing my scripts and apps usually bypasses the hassle of gatekeeper

Comment: That's a really good idea @wch1zpink! That had not crossed my mind, thanks.

Comment: This isn't 100% clear in the question—while this panel still exists under Mojave, it does not have the desired affect.

Super, super, super annoying! These are apps that I wrote for use on my own computer. I can't pay for a developer account just for them!

Comment: @Wowfunhappy you can create a developer account for free (Which has its limits) But In doing so, it will allow you to code sign your AppleScript applications. Code signed applications on your computer that you created don't need to be added to the list of apps allowed to control your computer

Comment: @wch1zpink I didn't realize free accounts could sign mac apps in a way that lets them through Gatekeeper. Regardless, it apparently doesn't apply in this situation, since in Mojave the dialogue still appears for signed apps.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue one user is being prompted for authorisation for "BASH" to run and "RC", The problem is we are unsure of the origin of the apps.

After poking around in activity monitor I've found whats using them and have allowed them to run the pop ups haven't reoccurred since.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer to the "Permanently grant right to control another app to Apple Script App" Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408028/24706) solved this exact issue for me in Mojave:

Lock the file/script/application being executed.

Instant fix for me, no more prompts!

Comment: The linked answer doesn't "work". It prevents the application from modifying itself. This means you are preventing an aspect of the program from working. This may well be desired, however doing so will cause unexpected behaviour in the application.

Answer (score 0):

In the past we've used the following terminal command to give the user the ability to "Allow apps from anywhere" and this eliminated the need to add apps to Accessibility:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

That has worked great with Sierra and High Sierra but this new Automation tab in Mojave (installed public release today) seems to be working differently.  Even with the above terminal change we are being prompted to allow all of our apps to control Finder and System Events.  Though, I've found other code signed applications, like Adobe Bridge, have to prompt with this same message as well.  Not sure if there is a way around it.

I'm hoping that accepting each dialog once will prevent the message from appearing again with future app updates that we send out.  Will be testing that out now.  Otherwise will have to test out the developer/code signed route.

Comment: I'm guessing that someone thought this sounds like a serious security hazard.

Comment: I am the one who downvoted this. It has nothing to do with the question, which was specifically regarding the new Apple Event sandbox dialogs that are both unrelated to Gatekeeper and exclusive to Mojave.