# Edit TCC.db to bypass "'Foo.app' wants access to control 'Bar.app'" on own machine

Tags: applescript, mojave, macos

I make extensive use of Apple Events to control a wide variety of applications on my machine. The new security prompts introduced in Mojave are *crippling*.

[image]

In previous versions of macOS, once an app was granted permission to "control your computer", it was able to send Apple events to any other app on your machine. In Mojave, this permission must be manually granted once for each app being controlled.

Once a user grants access, their selection is stored in one of two sqlite databases:

1. `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db`
2. `/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db`

   - Note that #2 is only visible to the root user.
   - Note that System Integrity Protection is disabled.

Would it be possible to edit these sqlite databases directly to automatically grant permissions and bypass these security prompts?

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks, SIP is already disabled on my machine. It doesn't look like that python program is compatible with Mojave's new "Automation" protection.

Comment: What sends Apple Events to the various apps (i.e how many Foo.app do you have and how many Bar.app do you have and is that matrix sparse or dense?)? Are you OK with a solution that doesn't scale past 3 machines you control (or requires funds at that point)?

Comment: @bmike My applescripts have lines like "tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to quit", so Bar.app could be any installed app. This is all on a single machine.

Comment: Get it all out of the way in one go: `tell app "Finder" to open every application file in the entire contents of (path to applications folder) as alias list`.  Then `repeat with A in the result`...`ignoring application responses`...`quit the application named A`...`end ignoring`...`end repeat`.  It'll be painful, but it'll be like ripping a bandaid off.

Answer (score 9):

To access the TCC.db database directly is no longer supported by Apple, **even if you disable SIP**, because of their policy of protecting users from big companies that like to track everything you do online, and also used to do this stealthy bypass without asking permission to users. However, even in Mojave, there is a way to circumvent this, but with a catch: **that only works if a given computer is enrolled in an MDM program**. To know more about the MDM program go [here](https://www.apple.com/business/it/).

In order to bypass this for several computers you can use the python script `tccprofile.py` available at [GitHub](https://github.com/brysontyrrell/tccprofile).

As far as I know, this is the only way to bypass the need to ask user permission from Mojave onwards.

Comment: It really isn't practical to obtain an MDM profile for my own personal scripts. With SIP disabled, what exactly is preventing me from editing the database? I recognize that the system itself can't be directly turned off, but without SIP I should be able to edit any file on my computer, including the database that stores all the whitelists.

Comment: Apparently, Apple changed the way it accesses this database by using the private API guarded_open_np. I already saw some posts of Russian hackers trying to reverse engineer this API with IDA Pro, but so far without great success.

Comment: Regardless of how Apple would normally edit the whitelist, it appears to be a standard sqlite database, as evidenced by the fact that it can be opened and read in database editors. If there is another reason why the file is impossible to directly edit and replace (for example, if macOS stores a checksum of the databse, and that checksum is itself encrypted by Apple), I would like to see a clear and comprehensive explanation of this in your answer! Thank you.

Comment: +1, but I don't trust blogs. Can we take the content from that website and quote it directly or add it to drive or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I found this for deleting an entry.

> `sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/Tcc.db`
>   'delete from access where client like "`%appnamehere%`"'
>
> Replace "`appnamehere`" with the name of the app as it appears in the
>   Accessibility list (keep the % signs).

Comment: This would remove an app from the database, not add permissions, right? It didn't appear to do anything when I tried it (add or remove).

Comment: In Catalina you inexplicably can't even *see* the file as *root*... `Error: unable to open database "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db": unable to open database file`, and if I try to `ls` the directory as root I get `ls: : Operation not permitted`.

Comment: @Michael was you able to read `TCC.db` on Catalina? I have the same problem as well, can't even do `ls` in `com.apple.TCC` directory

Comment: @WallTearer Yes, I have to enable full access to the filesystem to Terminal and/or /bin/bash under security and privacy in System Preferences

Comment: @Michael cool, thank you! At the same moment I was also reading following article with similar suggestion to enable Full Disk Access - https://blog.kolide.com/macos-catalina-osquery-a6753dc3c35c In the end I granted access to iTerm2 and was able to read security settings with tccutil.py utility like `sudo tccutil --list` (https://github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil)

Answer (score 0):

SIP does not support Library directory. So, it means you can still write to the TCC.db file through the terminal by some commands.

Here is the link : 
[About SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)

Comment: The TCC.db files are protected by SIP even though their directories are not. I don't care regardless—I'd just very much like to know _what_ commands will let me whitelist applications.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362865/macos-list-apps-authorized-for-full-disk-access/372596#372596            this link may help your query